# How to write a cmake function with more than one parameter groups?

Tags: cmake

For example, I want write a `my_add_lib` function with the following syntax:

```
my_add_lib(NAME <name>
           SRCS [src1 [src2 ...]]
           DEPS [dependency1 [dependency2 ...]]])
```

How to do implement these "parameter group"?

Comment: Just use the standard module [CMakeParseArguments](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#module:CMakeParseArguments), don't rewrite the wheel.

Comment: @julp Yeah! It is what I am seeking for. I hope you can make it an answer so that I can vote up and accept it! Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

CMake provides [CMakeParseArguments](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeParseArguments.html) module which can do arguments parsing for you. Example:

```
include(CMakeParseArguments)

function(my_add_lib)
    cmake_parse_arguments(
        PARSED_ARGS # prefix of output variables
        "" # list of names of the boolean arguments (only defined ones will be true)
        "NAME" # list of names of mono-valued arguments
        "SRCS;DEPS" # list of names of multi-valued arguments (output variables are lists)
        ${ARGN} # arguments of the function to parse, here we take the all original ones
    )
    # note: if it remains unparsed arguments, here, they can be found in variable PARSED_ARGS_UNPARSED_ARGUMENTS
    if(NOT PARSED_ARGS_NAME)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "You must provide a name")
    endif(NOT PARSED_ARGS_NAME)
    message("Provided sources are:")
    foreach(src ${PARSED_ARGS_SRCS})
        message("- ${src}")
    endforeach(src)
endfunction(my_add_lib)
```

As of CMake 3.5, `cmake_parse_arguments` becomes a builtin command (written in C++ instead of CMake): `include(CMakeParseArguments)` is no longer required but, for now, the file CMakeParseArguments.cmake is kept empty for compatibility.

Comment: If, like me, you are converting an existing function to use `cmake_parse_arguments()`, you may make the same mistake I did and forget to eliminate the former arguments of the function from the function signature. In that situation, `${ARGN}` will not be the arguments passed in by the caller. Instead, for me, it was a strange mash-up of the argument names I'd specified to `cmake_parse_arguments()`, and the names of variables I'd later assigned to my original arguments in the body of my function.